# fade on background image change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a botton which is for changing the background image with jquery, as the following code shows

```
$("#button").click(function() { 
  $('#div1').css("background-image", "url(images/newBG.jpg)");
});
```

it works very fine! but i want to fade in the newbg-image... is it possible to add a jquery fade method to it.
Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks Ted

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5002651/1606729

Comment: Background images don't have an `opactiy` property, so this is not possible. If you really need that fade, you should use an actual `img` element instead.

Comment: No it's not possible to fade the background without fading the entire contents of the div. You could instead have a `absolutely` positioned `img` which you can then fade in/out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery: fade css background image change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002351/jquery-fade-css-background-image-change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#button").click(function() { 
  $('#div1').hide().css("background-image", "url(images/newBG.jpg)").fadeIn(500);
});
```