# Changing background images with JQuery for different divs

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code and this script:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#unua').hover(function() {
     $('#pagina').css('background-image', 'url(imagini/1.png)');
   }, function() {
     $('#pagina').css('background-image', '');
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pagina">
  <div id="primalinie">
    <div id="unu" class="cerculet">
      <div id="unua">
        <a href="http://tineriiuniti.ro/contact/">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="doi" class="cerculet">
      <div id="doia">
        <a href="http://tineriiuniti.ro/despre-atu/">About Us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can you tell what's the problem here? The ID "pagina", is for the whole page.
Let me clear you out the problem. I will want whenever a user is with the mouse over one div the background image of the site will change. Different div, different image.
:(

Comment: Your script will work, provided the image is present in `imagini/` folder. Can you tell what do you see in the Console tab of the Chrome or Firebug? Also make sure you use jQuery and it gets loaded before your script is executed.

Comment: If image is present in `imagini ` directory then it should work. You can see it working for background color [here](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/e5xx9t00/)

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's what I was about to say: https://jsfiddle.net/3snzmLyy/

Comment: It does work now, thank you guys! I didn't loaded the jQuery :)) Still morning for me :D

Comment: And how can I add an effect there? to ease in and opacity? :/

Answer (score 1):

To ease in, take a look at this question: [How to fade changing background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002351/jquery-fade-css-background-image-change)

replace `$('#pagina').css('background-image', 'url(imagini/1.png)');`

with

```
$('#elem').fadeTo('slow', 0.3, function() {
    $(#pagina).css('background-image', 'url(imagini/1.png)');
}).fadeTo('slow', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to have your websites background image to change when ever you hover some element? And the way you want to do that is by changing `div#pagina`'s background, but the `div`'s height is not covering the whole page? At least that's what the code here is showing?

Well, in that case, since your `jQuery` is already doing the `background-image` swapping on the `div`, the only thing you have to do is to set the height of the `div#pagina`. 
You can do that by setting it's `height to 100%`, but it's parents also have to have height 100%, and it usually takes some tweaking to make it look right.

Other solution I would suggest is made out of two parts:

1. Add the background image on the `body` element if possible
2. Define the image as a `background-image` in your css, if possible, and assign a class for it, like this `.pagina-background-image { background-image: 'path/to/img.jpeg'}`. This way you can add transitions to the background, such as fade in and similar more efficiently with CSS.

Also, I'd suggest for you to optimize the `jQuery` a bit.
You can check the console log when you hover the `div` with text "test".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $pagina = $('#pagina');

  $pagina.hover(function() {
    $pagina.toggleClass('background-image');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pagina">test</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I've posted another comment here, about this page, can you help me pls? 10q

Comment: I'll check it out later today. Peace.

Answer (score 1):

I come with some changes about this page :( Now, they want that the background-image on hover to be a live preview ...
So i set the iframe box like this:

```
<div id="unu" class="cerculet"><div id="unua"><a href="http://tineriiuniti.ro/contact/">Contact</a><div class="box"><iframe src="http://tineriiuniti.ro/contact/" width = "500px" height = "500px"></iframe></div></div>
        </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.box {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

a:hover + .box,.box:hover{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

But it is displayed as a pop-up. How can I change this making in an background image?

Comment: I've tried like this but it doesn't work:
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').hide();
  });
    $('#unua').hover(function() {
    $('#pagina').css('background-image', $('.box'));
    });
  }, function() {
    $('#pagina').css('background-image', '');
  });

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what does the "live preview" mean? Some other internal page or external page?

Comment: Internal pages, links from them... Let me explain, I have a page with circles as a menu, and when I hover a circle to have in background the live preview like in this picture : 
http://imgur.com/bRbiFUz