# Change Background image url of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a div for which i want to show multiple images in the background as a fade in fade out by changing the css background image am unable to find the best way.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S59EW/138/)

My HTML:

```
<div id="background"></div>
```

Jquery

```
var bgArr = ["http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg", "http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg", "images/TopImage-03.jpg"];
var i = 0;

// Start the slide show
var interval = self.setInterval("swapBkgnd()", 5000)

function swapBkgnd() {
  if (i > (bgArr.length - 1)) {
    i = 0
    $("#background").css("background-image", "url(" + bgArr[i] + ")");
  } else {
    $("#background").css("background-image", "url(" + bgArr[i] + ")");
  }
  i++;
};
```

CSS:

```
#background {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ayEwJpMGTPQ/USqliwPWo1I/AAAAAAAAHtI/ab6NHVy0Q48/s1600/tree.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ook3ah4p/

```
var interval = self.setInterval(swapBkgnd, 5000) // true syntax
```

instead of:

```
var interval = self.setInterval("swapBkgnd()", 5000) // wrong syntax
```

for animation:

```
$('#background')
    .animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
        $(this)
            .css({'background-image': "url(" + bgArr[i] + ")"})
            .animate({opacity: 1});
    });
```

Comment: superb working fine but fade effect is not happening

Comment: you want to add fading effect while image changes right?

Comment: @shaik This is the right answer, the fade effect should be done by you.

Comment: first thanks for the help i have a problem that is fading entire div that should be not the case coz the content in the div is also fading

Comment: if you can help me on this wold be more help full for me

Comment: so you just want to animate image?

Comment: yes on the background the any content in that should not fade

Comment: sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0):

Set it up like this:

```
function swapBkgnd() {
  if (i > (bgArr.length - 1)) {
    i = 0;
  }
  $("#background").fadeOut("slow", function () {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + bgArr[i] + ")");
    $(this).fadeIn("slow");
  });
  i++;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Refering to this answer [How to fade changing background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002351/jquery-fade-css-background-image-change)

```
var interval = self.setInterval(swapBkgnd, 5000)

function swapBkgnd() {
    if (i > (bgArr.length - 1)) {
        i = 0
        $('#background').fadeTo('slow', 0.3, function(){
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + bgArr[i] + ')');
        }).fadeTo('slow', 1);
    } else {
        $('#background').fadeTo('slow', 0.3, function(){
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + bgArr[i] + ')');
        }).fadeTo('slow', 1);
}
i++;
};
```