# How animate background-image changes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to create a repeating `pulsing heartbeat` visual effect for a button.

I don't believe this can be done in CSS.

But how do you animate a background-image change in `jQuery` or `JS`?

I want to be able to do the following

```
$(this).animate({
     'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, white, red)',
     'background-image': '-linear-gradient(top, white, red)'
 }, 4000);
```

But jQuery does not allow non-numerical value in the CSS map.

Thanks.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983957/animate-background-image-change-with-jquery

Comment: You are correct that you cannot animate css backgrounds with css3 animations (currently). You can animate background images (Chrome 18 only at this point). jQuery doesn't allow direction animation of gradient's either.

Answer (score 0):

You can code your own animation using `cssHooks` - create a fake CSS style key that sets the background the way you want and takes a number as its value, then that fake style can be used in `.animate()`.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/

Alternatively, if you animate another property you can use the `step` callback to manually make your changes (not recommended unless you're using a very old version of jQuery).