# Is it possible to configure JQuery 'unslider' to change only backgrounds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

View my source here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bvkjx

Notice that the content rotates correctly, and so does the background image.

Now, is it possible to maintain for example

```
<p>SOME CONTENT1</p>
```

and only rotate the background images?

For unslider go [here](http://unslider.com)

Comment: While examples are great and should be encouraged, they should not be used in place of including the relevant code in the question itself. Please include the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would just like to change the background image, you can do it with either Javascript or jQuery:

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("some-li-id").style.backgroundImage="url(some-img.png)";
```

jQuery:

```
$("#some-li-id").css("background-image","url(some-img.png)");
```

If you would like to animate the background image change, you can do something like the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983957/animate-background-image-change-with-jquery) (you aren't limited to using .fadeIn/.fadeOut).